# How to use FormsAuthenticationTicket in asp.net core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core

This is my code.

```
protected UserDataModel GetUserDataFromAuthenticationCookie()
{
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("authCookie", Request.Cookies[GetCookieKey()]);
    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["authCookie"] != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket =
            FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(HttpContext.Request.Cookies["authCookie"]);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDataModel>(authTicket.UserData);
    }

    return null;
}
```

I am trying to decrypt cookie data using `FormsAuthentication` in asp.net core. But it raise build errors for `FormsAuthentication`. How to implement the deccrypt cookie data in asp.net core

Comment: Take a look at [FormsAuthentication](https://github.com/synercoder/FormsAuthentication) project.

Comment: Did anyone find a nice solution here? It's a pity when we want to migrate the project to asp.net core. This will make a huge change for our work based on Form Authentication logic.Why the asp.net core team give up these methods?

Comment: Anyone reading this can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072011/aspnetcore-alternative-for-system-web-security-formsauthenticationticket